# What software can be used to make book cover designs?

Tags: windows-7, graphic-design

I know GIMP and inkscape can be used but are there any specialized open source or freeware softwares that can be used specially to design book covers?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: I don't think that there's specialized software. The guys over at Graphics Design sometimes have [book cover challenges](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2767/21109) and my guess is that they use some Adobe software, which is close to GIMP or Inkscape (if it shall be gratis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Scribus

I am not sure what is so special about book covers, but I guess it is a combination of images and text.

So I used **[Scribus](http://scribus.net)** to create DVD and CD Covers. It is available for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: I should had mentioned it in the question but I was wondering if these "special"(that I termed) had a functionality of exporting it into a different format(perhaps optimized for printing)?